# Include code in Linkedin post

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to write a linkedin post and I need to include some code. I have been checking some options on the internet ([link](http://test.h2oconsulting.be/blog/gist-to-png?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_pulse_read%3Bb%2B13SMh%2BSVCotwMQ2EwHPw%3D%3D)) but it is still not very clear to me.

Any idea on how to do it?

--- EDIT ---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: looks like linkedin is using a small subset of the **Pulse article editor** that **only accepts images**.

My recomendation is: https://carbon.now.sh/

Comment: if using blocks ```, I just have to write my text between ```, e.g. ```my_text``` and then publish it? 
Could you explain how to use github gist, I have never try it before

Comment: Yes exactly @gcgm

Comment: I have tried your approach with different modifications but it is not working. Am I missing something? (the image belongs to the article once published)

Comment: Im sorry, I didn't know linkedin was using a simplified version of Pulse. I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, seems a very nice solution

Comment: You can also use this new tool : kodeshot [www.codeshot.net](https://www.kodeshot.net)